# Can anybody recommend a PDF solution for the Compact Framework?

Tags: .net, pdf, compact-framework, components

We have a requirement to generate PDF documents using information from a PDA / Mobile Phone. We cannot send the information back to a server as the information is required immediately and the engineers with the devices may be out of coverage.

So, can anybody recommend a .NET compact framework component for producing PDFs?

Could you also tell me about your experiences with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/products.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check iTextSharp

[iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)